# jquery ui progress bar only shows after loading all data from json

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I'm loading about 8000 records from an ajax call that returns json.
The json tells me how many total records, and breaks them down into 3 categories.

My HTML looks like:

```
<div id="tlWrapper">
        loading supporting data...
        <div class="clr10"></div>
        <div id="tableLoader"></div>
</div>
```

and the script in the ajax return

```
$.ajax({    
    url: "cgi/supportTables.exe",    
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",       
    data: dataString,
    error: ajaxError,           
    success: function(json){        
            if(json.error !== "0"){
                spinner(0);
                alertify.alert("ERROR "+json.error);                            
                return;
            }               

            var i=0;                
            var gCounter=0;

            //techsDB
            for( i=0;i<=json.techs.length-1;i++){
                  gCounter++;
                    progress(gCounter,json.grossCount);             
            }

            // clients
            for( i=0;i<=json.clients.length-1;i++){
                  gCounter++;               
                    progress(gCounter,json.grossCount);                 
            }         

            // clients techs per client
            for( i=0;i<=json.clientTechs.length-1;i++){                     
                  gCounter++;               
                  progress(gCounter,json.grossCount);       
            }
```

the progress function

```
function progress(counter,total){     
        var percent=parseInt( (counter/total)*100 );        
        $( "#tableLoader" ).progressbar( "option", "value", percent );              
}
```

My problem is that the progress bar doesn't display until everything is done, or 100% complete.
I tried adding a setInterval

```
var int=setInterval(function(){     
    var percent=parseInt( (counter/total)*100 );        
    if( percent=100 ){ clearInterval(int) };
    $( "#tableLoader" ).progressbar( "option", "value", percent );              
},1);
```

but had the same result.
How can I get it to show progress as expected?

Comment: This is the expected result I think. Unless you're performing HTTP calls at an interval to get progress on another job.

Comment: Each of the `for()` loops will run until they reach the end of the array. Also each loop is sending data to the same progress bar.

Comment: I *want* them all to go to the same progress bar.

Comment: Then they will, all at once and it will go from 0 to 100% all at once.

Comment: I have the total number of records in all 3 tables (about 8000).
I have a global counter 1-8000.
As I loop through, counter grows incrementally and I send the value in a percentage. I don't understand why it waits until it's all done before displaying 100% complete.

Comment: This is the asynchronous nature of JavaScript.

Comment: Check out jquery's [deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) object.